# Jquery - Duplicate span price value to form input without euro sign or comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price span and need to duplicate its numerical value into a form input without the euro sign or comma.

The code is

```
<span class="main-price">€25,960</span>
<input id="fieldname2_1" class="field number small valid" type="number" value="20000" max="100000" min="0" name="fieldname2_1">
```

And I need the number only so clone over 25960.

How would I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way, but you'd probably want it more dynamic, and to account for different currencies and formatting I'm guessing.

```
var price = $('.main-price').text().replace('€', '').replace(',', '');
$('#fieldname2_1').val(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will replace everything that is not a number or a decimal point.

```
       price = $(".main-price").text();
       price = price.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
       $("#fieldname2_1").val(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular expression

```
var number_only = $(".main-price").text().replace('€','').match(/\d+/);
$("#fieldname2_1").val( number_only);
```